# Confine contents to absolutely placed container

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create an overlay for a webpage. However, content in the overlay does not take the overlay's height but rather the page height

```css
#detail {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  z-index: 2;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

#full {
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 2px solid green;
}
```

```html
  <div id='detail'>
    <div>
      <h2>Summary</h2>
      This is intended to be the summary of the "lorem ipsum" text that follows
    </div>
    <div id='full'>
      <h3>Complete article</h3>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
      sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea
      rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </div>
  </div>
```

I have tried variants, such as adding an in-between  with relative positioning, but still the #full container assumes the screen height

Comment: please elaborate and tell your problem precisely

Comment: You need to provide the absolute element with actual length **units**. `100` is not enough...100 *what?* - Try `100%` etc.

Comment: Don't use duplicated id's. An id need to be unique. Also what is that `</style>` close tag doing there?

Comment: @AKASH PANDEY: I would like to see the "full" text below the heading (it is there) but confined to the 300px by 300px overlay box, i.e. with a scrollbar. When I check "computed layout", it shows 300 for the outer box but the screen height (rather than remaining space) on the inner one

Comment: @Mark Baijens: script example fixed... According to "computed layout", Firefox considers the values to be pixels

Comment: @user1938139 so you want the red border to be enclosing the green bordered element

Comment: @Mark Baijens: yes - that is true

Answer (score 0):

With a calculated height you can achieve what you want i think.

```css
#detail {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  z-index: 2;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

#full {
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 2px solid green;
  height: calc(100% - 110px);
}
```

```html
<div id='detail'>
    <div>
      <h2>Summary</h2>
      This is intended to be the summary of the "lorem ipsum" text that follows
    </div>
    <div id='full'>
      <h3>Complete article</h3>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
      sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea
      rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Hi, this looks quite good, but unfortunately I cannot use the measured height of the top part, just a constant. It seems that the real content of the top part can vary in length quite a bit